# Cant see data after importing in _post form

Tags: php, post

Hey i am using Mamp on imac and my problem is that when i hit the submit button (on a post form) to enter the data then nothing shows up and the database remains empty.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'demob');
define('DB_USER','brom');
define('DB_PASSWORD','****');
Define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
die('cant use' . DB.NAME . ' : ' .mysql_error());
 }

 $value = $_POST['input1'];

 $sql = "INSER INTO memberss ('input1') VALUES ('$value')";



 mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Comment: You have an SQL syntax error, *INSER INTO memberss* should be **INSERT** *INTO memberss*

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing a query.

```
$sql = "INSER INTO memberss ('input1') VALUES ('$value')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

You should know that, the method you are using to connect to mysql is deprecated now. please read up about `PDO` or `mysqli`